# What are the Solidity contracts that the Infura NFT SDK uses? How can one test these contracts?

Tags: nft, infura, truffle-test

I am trying to make use of the [Infura NFT SDK](https://docs.infura.io/infura/infura-custom-apis/nft-sdk) that would work with another contract that I developed. I wanted to make some unit tests locally, however, searching on their documentation and on the files of the [package itself](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@infura/sdk), I cannot find any `.sol` file and, despite them mentioning that ["The underlying contract definitions use OpenZeppelin templates"](https://docs.infura.io/infura/infura-custom-apis/nft-sdk), if I check the bytecode of the ERC721.sol or the ERC721Royalty.sol against what is produced by their "ERC721Mintable", the bytecodes are different.

Is there any way that I can do these unit tests without the Solidity file?

P.S.:

1. I am using the Truffle Suite so if there is a workaround please let me know;
2. None of the contracts on Goerli with the same bytecode have a verified contract, but here is the address to one of them [0xc3d8b967f38ee69d42def39072be3c381f396835](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xc3d8b967f38ee69d42def39072be3c381f396835);
3. I found a JSON file related to their supposed "ERC721Mintable" contract in which I have the following keys:

```
contractName
abi
metadata
bytecode
deployedBytecode
immutableReferences
generatedSources
deployedGeneratedSources
sourceMap
deployedSourceMap
source
sourcePath
ast
compiler
networks
schemaVersion
updatedAt
devdoc
userdoc
db
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The Infura NFT API doesn't *use* solidity files, so much as it points to certain endpoints on the chain and returns data. This API can be programmed to yield datas, the architecture for which could be in `curl` or `python` or `javascript`.

You're trying to 

> make some unit tests

...so the question is, what are you trying to test, and what exactly (you don't have to give your game away here) are you trying to achieve with your tests? What data are you trying to attain? Could you give some examples?

Comment: @XaEk it can't? But following the SDK documentation they show an example on [how to deploy new contracts](https://docs.infura.io/infura/infura-custom-apis/nft-sdk/how-to/deploy-a-contract#deploy-the-nft-contract). I thought the SDK and the API were offered as the same service.
Regarding my testing, I want to test that the contract I've developed can transfer the tokens (from the contract created with the Infura NFT SDK / API) as expected in the solidity code I've wrote, hence the need of an instance of the contract I can deploy with the Infura NFT SDK / API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the SDK allows that, but your question asked about API.

To answer your question;

**Infura can call any deployed, on-chain contracts and read their datas**. Thereby it "uses" **any** deployed contract. You *may have* written these contracts yourself - and you may have not. Etiehr way, you're able to use Infura to interact with them.

It's worth clarifying that the API isn't built on Solidity/using smart contracts. But it **is built *to be able to interact with them***:

In your case, since you have developed an NFT contract using the Infura SDK, then you will be able to further use the Infura API to test the contract(s) pre-deployment, by writing tests in something like `javascript`.

I would go through the [hardhat tutorial](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts) and see how tests can be written in `js`, wherein you use `Alchemy` to instantiate the contracts and run tests thereafter.

Alternatively, go through the [truffle tutorial](https://docs.infura.io/infura/tutorials/ethereum/deploy-a-contract-using-truffle) utilising `Infura` to connect to your desired chain, and test contracts therein.

Comment: Thank you for your input! However, I can test these contracts deployed with the SDK with my own on a public testnet, but what I am asking is regarding unit testing that I want to do locally using Truffle. I have edited the question so that I am more precise on what I am asking